# lateinit property navigationManager has not been initialized in multimodule compose app using Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

NavigationManager in App module is not initialized by Hilt

kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property navigationManager has not been initialized

Navigation graph next to provideNavigationManager() in the AppModule points to the NavigationManager lateinit var in the MainActivity.
When I create a TestObject in the app module and provide it in the AppModule, I get the same error, so I don't expect this to be a multi-module issue.

[image]

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
 class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

@Inject lateinit var navigationManager: NavigationManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        ChopieTheme {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            navigationManager.commands.collectAsState().value.also { command ->
            ...
     }
```

:project gradle

```
 dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha02")
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10")
    classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.37")
 }
```

:app

```
 dependencies {
    implementation(project(":core"))
    implementation(project(":navigation"))
 ...
 }


@HiltAndroidApp
class ChopieApp : Application() {}


@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object AppModule {

   @Singleton
   @Provides
   fun provideApplication(@ApplicationContext app: Context): ChopieApp {
      return app as ChopieApp
   }

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  fun provideNavigationManager() = NavigationManager()
}
```

:core (library module)

```
 plugins {
   id("com.android.library")
   id("kotlin-android")
   kotlin("kapt")
   id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
 }
...
dependencies {
// DI
api("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.35")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.37")
api("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03")
...
}
```

:navigation (library module)

```
 dependencies {
   implementation(project(":core"))
 ...
 }

class NavigationManager {
...
}
```

Comment: Multimodule shouldn't be an issue here. Can you try clean and build again. Also, this field injection should resolve at compile time in dagger hilt. Its shouldn't show error at runtime

Comment: Clean/Rebuild didn't help. Perhaps this is a kapt issue. If I go to build/generated/source, there is no kapt, which should be there with dagger generated files including BaseApplication_hiltComponents class, which in turn should include all the component modules.
Currently, the Hilt dependency is in the :core module, exposed to all other moduels. I added kotlin("kapt") and/or id("kotlin-kapt") plugins, but none of which seem to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue in the two-step process:

1. I changed the dagger:hilt-android version to match the kapt hilt-android-compiler version.
2. I removed dagger.hilt plugin and all hilt dependencies from the :core module, and then I added them to :app and :navigation modules (api was changed to implementation)